# They are all names of Movies ; aren't they?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

Here is a simple list of some of my favorite movies. Please fill out the blank. I will even give you 4 choices!

> 1 The Sting
>
> 2 In the Heat of the Night
>
> 3 ?
>
> 4 Unforgiven
>
> 5 Braveheart
>
> 6 The Aviator

The ? is one of these four choices

> The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
>
> The Bridge on the River Kwai
>
> Rififi
>
> Slumdog Millionaire

Please explain your choice. Knowledge tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the missing film is:

> **Rififi**

Why? Because...

> If you look at just the letters in each film's title which are Roman numerals, they form the Roman equivalent of their number in the list:
>
>  1 The St**I**ng (I)
>  2 **I**n the Heat of the N**I**ght (II)
>  3 R**I**f**I**f**I** (III)
>  4 Unforg**IV**en (IV)
>  5 Bra**V**eheart (V)
>  6 The A**VI**ator (VI)
>
>  The remaining choices do not work:
>
>  The **L**or**D** of the R**I**ngs: The Fe**LL**owsh**I**p of the R**I**ng  (LDILLII)
>  The Br**ID**ge on the R**IV**er Kwa**I** (IDIVI)
>  S**L**u**MD**og **MILLI**ona**I**re (LMDMILLII)

Comment: That was the logic! Kudos.

Comment: Thanks :) Nice brainteaser! The comment about 'no knowledge tag required' threw me for a bit but when I spotted it you could have drawn a light bulb over my head!

Comment: @Stiv how does Rififi has 7 hidden inside it ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal It doesn't - it has **3**, which is its position in the list

Comment: oh..yeah...sorry .